# Regroup javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I would like to format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "location 1"
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "location": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "location 1"
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "location": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "location 2"
        },
    }
]
```

To:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "location 1",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "id": 2,
        "title": "location 2",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Update:
From your responses I derived:

```
const result = _(items)
    .groupBy(x => x.location.id)
    .map((value, key) => ({location: key, items: value}))
    .value();
```

Which works, but the item objects still contain the location attribute and the location only maintains its id attribute. Is it neccessary to add all attributes to the groupBy?

The reason I am doing this is because I would like to filter on item attributes, but display the items grouped by location.

Comment: Did you try anything? I see lodash tag.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Hi Vincent, guess I have asked a similar question before, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220367/group-objects-array-underscore-js/28220475 The question was related to underscore.js, but perhaps it still helps.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Collect the items using [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) on the `location.title`, then [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) them. To create an object, use the key (2nd param) for the `location`, take the `id` from the 1st item using [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get), and map the other items to take just the location object without the `title` using [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit):

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"location":{"id":1,"title":"location 1"}},{"id":2,"location":{"id":1,"title":"location 1"}},{"id":3,"location":{"id":2,"title":"location 2"}}];

const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('location.title')
  .map((items, location) => ({
    location,
    id: _.get(items, '[0].id'), // get the 1st item (if any) id
    items: items.map(({ location }) => _.omit(location, 'title')) // map the objects and take the inner item without the title
  }))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace following code

```
const result = _(items)
    .groupBy(x => x.location.id)
    .map((value, key) => ({location: key, items: value}))
    .value();
```

with

```
const result = _(items)
    .groupBy(x => x.location.id)
    .map((value, key) => ({location: key, items: value.map(e => ({id: e.id}))}))
    .value();
```